# Random Number Resets

Tags: php, post, random

My random number generates on page load, but seems to reset when the user clicks the "Guess" button. I still have a lot of building to go with this, but at the end I want the user to be able to make multiple guesses to guess the random number. I want it to generate when the page first comes up and stay the same until correctly guessed. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong and just starting this program. If you answer, please also explain, as I'm trying to learn what I'm doing. Thank you!

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
        <title>PHP Homework 2</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/styles.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <section id="main">
            <h1>Play the Guessing Game!</h1>
            <section id="left">
                <h2>Take a Guess!</h2>
                <form action="mine.php" method="post">
                    <div id="guessBox">
                        <label id="guessLB">Your Guess:</label>
                        <input id="guessTB" class="num" type="number" name="guessTB" max="1000" min="1">
                        </input>
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" id="guessButton" name="guessBTN" value="Guess" />
                </form>
            </section>
            <section id="right">
                <h2>Game Stats</h2>
                <?php 

                    if(isset($_POST['guessTB'])) 
                    {
                        $randomNum = $_POST['guessTB'];
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                        $randomNum = rand(1,100);
                    }                       

                    echo "<p>Random Number: $randomNum</p>";
                ?>      
            </section>
        </section>          
    </body>
</html>
```

UPDATE: My HTML has remained the same, and I'm posting my new PHP code. But I used a session and wrote some more. However, I've come across two problems:

1) If I refresh the page, I get an error that says that the first instance of `$randomNum` below the `session_start();` is unidentified.

2) It seems that it remembers my very last guess in the game. If I close out the page and reopen it, I immediately get one of the messages that my guess was too high or too low, even before making a guess. Any advice is appreciated!

```
<?php
                    session_start();

                    $randomNum = $_SESSION['randomNum'];
                    $guess = $_POST['guessTB'];

                    if(!isset($_SESSION['randomNum']))
                    {
                        $_SESSION['randomNum'] = rand(1,1000);
                    }
                    else
                    {   
                        if($guess < $randomNum)
                        {
                            echo "<p>Your Guess is Too Low! Try Again!</p>";
                        }

                        else if($guess > $randomNum)
                        {
                            echo "<p>Your Guess is Too High! Try Again!</p>";
                        }

                        else
                        {
                            echo "<p>You Won!</p>";
                            $_SESSION = array();
                            session_destroy();
                        }
                    }           

                    echo "<p>Guess: $guess</p>";
                    echo "<p>Random Number: $randomNum</p>";
                ?>
```

Comment: Clicking the button reloads the page which calls the random number generator. Is that not what you expected?

Comment: No, that is not what I want. I still have a lot of building to go with this, but at the end I want the user to be able to make multiple guesses to guess the random number. I want it to generate when the page first comes up and stay the same until correctly guessed.

Comment: HTTP is by default *stateless*. The way the webserver "remembers" things about a user (in this case, the *correct* number) is typically via a [session variable](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php).

Comment: @JonathonReinhart - Thank you - I read on the sessions and think this will work if I generate the random number, set it to a session variable and check to see if its set. Right? But where do I actually do the generation to where it won't reoccur with every new guess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is use sessions. On every load check if you set it in the session and if it's not set, generate new number and set it, then check what the user input and compare the two numbers. This could also be done with cookies. Another thing you can do is use js. On load store the generated number in some js variable and don't use a form. On button click get the value of the input field and compare with the one you store in the variable.